# Is there a data structure that provides lookup by pattern (regex)?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, data-structures

I've run into this situation several times: there are multiple patterns some text may match against, and you want to do something specific based on which pattern it is.

In the past I've always just used a list of regular expressions and iterated until finding a match.

What I'm wondering is if there is a more efficient data structure for this. Something like, if I were using C# for example, a Dictionary with Regex keys.

I realize that if the patterns are all prefixes or suffixes, then something like a Trie would make sense. It's not clear to me that this would work for the general case, though.

It also seems to me there could be some ambiguity here around key collisions; e.g., if some text matches more than one pattern, what should be returned? (I would think that maybe a non-deterministic result would be OK in that case; but as long as the behavior were documented I'd be fine with it.)

Anyway, does such a data structure exist, either in .NET or elsewhere?

Comment: Might not be what you are looking for, but if using c# lists, use `FirstOrDefault(x=>doesItMatch(x))`. Still have to go through each one, but it will stop at the first one that works.

Comment: I'm not sure how possible it would be to do that in better than O(n).

Comment: @SLaks: I'm not sure either! But I've been blown away by clever data structures before.

Comment: If the regex expressions can be organized by their logical exclusivity (anything not matching pattern A cannot possible match pattern B, for instance) into a logical tree, then you can reduce the comparisons. The easiest data structure for the tree would be a linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that these regular expressions are truly regular. Each can then be converted into a [Nondeterministic Finite Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automata), which can be [converted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times) into a [Deterministic Finite Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), which can be evaluated in O(n) time in the length of the input.

But it doesn't address the question of matching multiple regexps at the same time. We can do this by creating a single regexp that looks like this: `(regexp1|regexp2|...)`, and turn *that* into a single NFA/DFA. Add some instrumentation to the branches of the automaton to keep track of which particular regexp produced the path that matched the input, and you've got your matcher, still O(n) in the length of the input string.

This technique would not support any "regex" features that make the language non-regular, [such as backreferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages).

Another drawback is that the resulting DFA could be large. It is also possible to evaluate the NFA directly, which is probably slower but has better memory behaviour.

---

Actually it's pretty easy to express this idea in code as well, without worrying about the automaton stuff. Just use matching groups:

```
combined_regexp = (regexp1)|(regexp2)|...
```

At evaluation time, just see which group matched the input.

Keep in mind that most regex implementations/libraries have pretty poor behaviour in some corner cases, where they can take exponential time to compile or match the regexp. I'm not sure how much of a problem that is in practice. Google's [RE2](https://code.google.com/p/re2/) library is one that was specifically designed not to have such pathological behaviour, but there might be others.

Another problem could be that, unless your regexp implementation specifically advertises O(n) behaviour, it might just try each of the alternatives in turn. In that case this approach wouldn't buy you anything.

Comment: I was thinking about something along these lines (constructing one big "master" Regex) myself. Do you know of any existing implementations? I'm guessing no, since you didn't mention any.

Comment: No, I don't. The only regex implementation that I know of that actually constructs an in-memory automaton is Google's [RE2](https://code.google.com/p/re2/).

Answer (score 4):

The fgrep tool does exactly what you're talking about: matches text against multiple regular expressions. My understanding is that the original version used something very similar to the [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) to search multiple regular expressions in a single pass. Basically, it created a DFA and ran through it.

I do not know of a .NET implementation of fgrep. If you find one, I'd certainly be interested to hear about it.

You might track down the fgrep source code (Google for it, there are lots of sources) and see how it's implemented.

Alternatively, you could have your program shell out to fgrep. Or perhaps create a C++ DLL that has an fgrep entry point that you could call from your C# program.

If your multiple patterns are constant strings (i.e. not regular expressions), then you might be interested in my [C# implementation of the Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=869).

Answer (score 0):

Few years back I made an implementation of a regex search engine based on a deterministic finite state machine, very similar to what Thomas describes in his answer. It compiles a list of regex keys and values into a single finite state automaton, which references objects of a defined type in its terminal states (for instance, RegexTrie references strings at terminal states).

The implementation is available here: https://bitbucket.org/tjnieminen/regexkeytrie

Standard search is performed by maintaining a list of paths through the machine. Each active path is advanced for each character of the search text, and matches are recorded whenever a terminal state is reached. A new path starting at the machine root is added for each character of the source text (this allows substring matches), and paths that stop at an non-terminal state are removed from the path list.

It's generally best to customize the processing for whatever the task is. For instance, if using the engine for regex replacements, it may be best to produce the edited text during the traversal (like a transducer), instead of performing find and replace actions with the returned matches.

I've benchmarked the implementation against normal .Net regexes, and it seems to do better in the scenarios where it should, i.e. with a combination of a large set of regexes and a long text to search.

The implementation hasn't been thoroughly tested, so there might be some bugs left, and it's probably fairly easy to run out of memory with complex regexes (or they might take forever to compile). But since there's nothing similar available at the moment, it might be a useful starting point for someone looking for the performance characteristics it provides.